# Make content of :before = the name of the element

Tags: css

Can I make the content of a pseudo-element the name of the pseudo-element’s parent?

Right now I am using brute force, setting content for each possible element:

```
abbr:before  { content: "abbr"  }
corr:before  { content: "corr"  }
expan:before { content: "expan" }
orig:before  { content: "orig"  }
reg:before   { content: "reg"   }
sic:before   { content: "sic"   }
```

(This is XML, not HTML. That is why the element names will look unfamiliar.)

Is there a CSS (non-Javascript) way to access an element’s name?

Comment: A SASS/LESS is your only way and I am pretty sure it can be easily done

Comment: (in Sass with a map) Yep, you can only access attribute values wih `attr()`

Comment: That's possible in CSS as well.